# How to protect Laravel model properties

Tags: laravel, eloquent

When working with other frameworks, or pure-PHP, I protect my model properties.  I then create public getters and setters where required, and proxy to them using `__get()` and `__set()`.  This helps me sleep at night.

Recently I started using Laravel and I am surprised at how 'unprotected' the Eloquent models are.  I understand that I can use the `$guarded` and `$fillable` properties to control mass assignment, but that still leaves a lot of room for accidental access.

For example, my model has a `status` property. It has a default value set on model creation, and should only be modified when `$model->activate()` or `$model->deactivate()` is called.  But by default, Laravel allows developers to modify it directly.  As far as I can see, the only way to prevent this is to create a setter, and throw an exception if it is called.

Am I missing something?  Perhaps I just need to relax?  What's the best way to build Eloquent models that are secure by default?

Comment: As per @divito answer, you could set an accessor for the field you want to protect and throw an exception if it gets called (e.g. you then know someone tried to change the field). However, that does then mean you have change it more manually via the ->attributes array for your activate() method. You probs will be fighting the framework a bit to work the way you are used to. It is designed to be fairly easy to learn and work with rather than being strict.

Answer (score 3):

You can override __get and __set method. You need to define an array protectedProperties and a boolean variable protectedChecks so you can control the model fields.

```
protected $protectedChecks = true;

protected $protectedProperties = [ 'status' ];

protected $fillable = ['status'];

public function __get($key)
{
    return (in_array($key, $this->fillable) && !in_array($key, $this->protectedProperties)) ? $this->attributes[$key] : null;
}

public function __set($key, $value)
{
    if(!$this->protectedChecks || !in_array($key, $this->protectedProperties))
            return parent::__set($key, $value);
        trigger_error('Protected Field');
}

public function activate()
{
    $this->protectedChecks = false;
    $this->status = 1;
    $this->save(); // this is optional if you want to save the model immediately
    $this->protectedChecks = true;
}
```

If you want to use every model you should write something like above in BaseModel.

Comment: This works just fine. If you want to be thorough, you should overwrite the `setAttribute()` method the same way as the `__set()` method.  
It is also possible to remove the `$this->protectedChecks` property and just call the setter  methods from `parent::` inside your model.

Answer (score -1):

**You may try:**

```
<?php

class User extends Eloquent {

     protected $hidden = array('password', 'token');

}
```

Comment: This hides the information from output when using things like ->toJson() it doesn't protect the changing of these values

Answer (score -1):

For what i see you probabely coming from symfony or other system that uses Mapping as a base to deal with database layer. Forget what you have done there as Eloquent uses Active Records an is different.
Best way is this: [Eloquent: Accessors & Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators)
Alo check in laracast there is explanation how to do it in old php fashion way using absolute properties.

Comment: ActiveRecord never forces you to use setters. From Domain perspective Eloquent models can still be used without setters. But modifying Eloquent model to forbid setters completely is a bit complicated.