# Unable to access protected variable within class when declaring variable

Tags: php, laravel, class, eloquent, lumen

I am new to laravel/php and was hoping someone would be able to answer a question for me. When I then use asset->setDescription here everything works fine but as soon as I uncomment 'protected $description' the setDescription method stops working. Does anyone know why this is happening?

````
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Asset extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'type', 'title','origin',
    ];
    // protected $description;
    public function __construct($type, $title, $origin)
    {
        $this->setType($type);
        $this->setTitle($title);
        $this->setOrigin($origin);
    }
    // Setters
    public function setType($type){
        $this->type = $type;
    }
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
    }
    public function setOrigin($origin)
    {
        $this->origin = $origin;
    }
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;
    }
}

$type = $request->input('type');
$title = $request->input('title');
$origin = $request->input('origin');

// Create new asset
$asset = new Asset($type, $title, $origin);
$asset->setDescription('test');

$asset->save();```
````

Comment: did you check your error logs etc. etc.

Comment: I didnt find any errors in the php_error.log file. It wont throw an error when I am making the call, it will just not update the database. I also made sure the description was making it to the setDescription function with a dd() and everything was there

Comment: How are you using it? It should work.

Comment: I just just revised the post to include the implementation

Comment: This is probably due to object inheritance, though I could be wrong. If you want to make description a protected attribute, then use `protected $protectedProperties = [ 'description' ];`  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46376646/how-to-protect-laravel-model-properties

Comment: From what I can tell from other posts the way that I have it above (with the line uncommented) SHOULD work, just trying to figure out what exactly is stopping it

Comment: What are you attempting to do here? Prevent description from being updated, make sure it's only updated via the function, or attempting to [mutate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators) the description when setting it?

Comment: Attempting to make sure its only updated via the function

Comment: As long as you use `setDescription($description)` to effect the `description` property this code should work

Comment: Yes, unfortunately when I uncomment the protected $description line it fails to update the entry in the database

Comment: You might want to check the link I provided above. It explains how to override the __get()/__set() functions to protect the property. Though I'm still not quite sure why it's not passing it back up to Eloquent when it's protected...

Comment: I checked out the link above and I think you are right as far as forcing it to work, out of curiosity though I am interested in figuring our why something so basic to php does not work with eloquent. Will report back when I figure it out.

Comment: Eloquent has no knowledge of that protected property. All Eloquent Model attributes are maintained through an attributes property. If you wish to accomplish setting values this way use the attributes property in your `setDescription` method: `$this->attributes['description'] = $description;` See [mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators) for more information.

Comment: @adam Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eloquent has no knowledge of that protected property. All Eloquent Model attributes are maintained through an attributes property. If you wish to accomplish setting values this way use the attributes property in your `setDescription` method:

```
public function setDescription($description)
{
    $this->attributes['description'] = $description;
}
```

See [mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators) for more information.